# Malicious node in ns2

Tags: networking, routes, ns2

I have an error while implementing malicious node in ns2 for the `AODV` routing protocol

```
$ns at 0.0 "[$node_(0) set ragent_] hacker"
```

[image: Screenshot is given, please help me to get rid of the error]

Comment: If possible post the whole script.

Answer (score 1):

Verify your node creation code. Error message itself very clear.

> It seems like, you are not defining it as node_(0).

Comment: I've followed all the instruction according to this link

http://karthicksivakrr.blogspot.in/2013/12/adding-malicious-node-to-aodv-ns2.html

then it's showing that error.

Comment: @ShankhaShubhraDas there is a possibility that the error is in tcl, where you define nodes for the environment. Go through it, once again. If thats not the case, without looking at your tcl code, i can't help you anymore..

Comment: can you provide your mail id please then I can send you tcl script

Answer (score 0):

---

> ns at 0.0 "[$node_(0) set ragent_] hacker"

Depends what you have defined in aodv.cc . ( ``hacker´ or `malicious´.)

Example, aodv-malicious_ns235.patch line 8 - 10 :

```
+if(strcmp(argv[1], "hacker") == 0) {
+malicious = true;
+return TCL_OK;
```

Malicious INFO  http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/malicious/ , and  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/malicious|sort:date/ns-users/meRJq7W0ZkQ/zV3WcZHlAQAJ → → 10/11/14

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use malicious or hacker as you defined.

```
$ns at 0.0 "[$n1 set ragent_] malicious
```